# ImportError: cannot import name timezone

Tags: django, django-nonrel

After installing django-norel, and running `python manage.py shell`, I get this error:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name timezone
```

using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, python 2.7.3, django 1.4, and last versions of 
django-nonrel, djangotoolbox and django-mongodb engine

It seems to be some kind of incompatibility problem. Should I use an earlier version of django? If so, how can I specify the django version on the install command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have both "Django 1.4" and "the latest version of django-nonrel". Django-nonrel *replaces* Django, and the latest version is built on Django 1.3, which doesn't have the `utils.timezone` module.

Comment: That's right. I just checked the django 1.3 tutorial, and they use `>>> import datetime` with 
`datetime.datetime.now())` instead of `timezone.now()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because timezone is a new function at Django 1.4.

Perhaps you installed multi-version Django at your machine, then reference to a version less than 1.4.

**How to check**

Type this at your **python manage.py shell**

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.path
```

You'll see all your current django environ paths.

Please check if include the right Django 1.4's root path at printed text.